# Get a random value from a range in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let suppose my table can have values from 000 to 999 (three digits and less than 1000)

Some of this values are filled. Let's suppose currently my table has

**000,002,005,190 (001,004,003,006,..189,191,..,999 can be inserted into table)**

and these values are randomly allocated 000 and 002 is in table but 001 is not in table yet.

How can I get the values that I can insert into table yet.

Comment: Are there any 3-digit numbers that are greater than 1000?

Comment: If numbers can't be repeated, you don't need to put a size limit on the table.

Comment: yes numbers can not be repeated but we have limit of 999.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the table could never contain all 1000 of the three-digit non-negative decimal integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(VALUE CHAR(3))

INSERT @t
VALUES
('000'),('002'),('005'),('190')


;WITH rnCTE
AS
(
    SELECT -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TYPE, number, name) AS rn
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
)
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST( rn AS VARCHAR(11)),3)
FROM rnCTE
WHERE NOT EXISTS    (   SELECT 1 FROM @t 
                        WHERE VALUE = rn
                    )
AND rn < 1000
```

**EDIT**

This query works by generating the complete list of possible numbers from a system table (`master.dbo.spt_values`) which is guaranteed to contain more than 1000 rows inside the CTE `rnCTE`. -1 is added to `ROW_NUMBER` to have the values start at 0 rather than 1.

The outer query zero pads the numbers for display, returning only those which are not in the source data and are less than 1000.

Comment: I solved this by writing following query.    
declare @count int;
select @count= 000
   create TABLE #Temporary_tbl 
     (                              
     stylecode decimal--varchar(20) 
                        )
    WHILE @count < 999
    begin
    set @count=@count+1
        select * from styles  where cast(stylecode as int)= @count   
       if(@@rowcount=0)
    begin
       insert into #Temporary_tbl(stylecode) select @count
    end
    
   end
 select top(1) from  #Temporary_tbl 
 drop table #Temporary_tbl
**Will you please optimize this query!**And Let me know working of your query

Comment: @Zain - edited the answer to explain how it works. There's not much scope to optimise your solution since it uses a `WHILE` loop - the solution I've suggested is set-based and should be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT)
INSERT INTO @t (id) 
VALUES 
(1),(19),(3)

;WITH numbers AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.object_id,o2.object_id) RN FROM sys.objects o
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
),  NotExisted AS(
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE RN NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM @t)
AND RN<1000)
SELECT TOP 1 RN FROM NotExisted ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a T-SQL to first query and find the gaps. There is no ready made SQL that will give you the gaps directly.

Comment: Ok can you guide me how to write query to find gaps?