# How can I get a random value from a range of numbers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Foremost, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960549/how-do-i-get-a-random-value-from-a-range-in-ms-sql) before posting, mine is not a duplicate, our questions are different beside the titles.

I don't have a big knowledge in SQLSERVER/T-SQL, so when I was "translating" some scripts from ORACLE/PLSQL, I didn't found any function to generate a random number between 2 values.

In the PLSQL script I'm looking at, I can get it simply using `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(5, 10)`.

How can I do that in T-SQL? Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a solution](http://sqlfool.com/2009/06/random-number-generator-in-tsql/)... Wonders of google

Comment: The first comment of that post helps more than the post itself, maybe I didn't had made it clear, but I wanted a built-in function or anything like it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `rand` function, which gives you a value 0 <= n < 1. Example for a number between 5 and 10 (inclusive):

```
floor(rand() * (10 - 5 + 1)) + 5
```